# Что означает словосочетание "представления детализации"?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, view

Что, в данном контексте, означает словосочетание "представления детализации"?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. То, что слово "представление" в  Android означает любой элемент вёрстки, я знаю, но с словосочетанием "представления детализации" раньше не сталкивался

Comment: Здесь "детализация" - это визуальное "представление" (окно) в котором отображаются элементы записи (конкретного "преступления"). Это классическое применение фрагментов: слева список, например меню в столовой, справа расширенное описание блюда с ценой и картинками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь слово представление вообще не относится к Android тематике.

В книге, которую Вы читаете автор использует общепринятое разделение приложения на логические модули, такие как уровень модели, уровень контроллера и уровень представления.

В приведенной Вами схеме есть модель, контроллер и представление для отображения **списка** преступлений. То есть эта часть приложения отвечает за список преступлений

В свою очередь `CrimeActivity` и `CrimeFragment` относятся к части приложения, отвечающей за отображение детальной информации по конкретному преступлению. И в этой части приложения `CrimeActivity` и `CrimeFragment` относятся к уровню (слою) представления. Условно, они - то, что увидит пользователь.

Таким образом

> представление детализации

в данном случае - набор классов, которые будут показаны пользователю в части приложения, отвечающей за просмотр детальной информации.

P.s. По поводу слоев приложения настоятельно советую ознакомиться с содержанием данной статьи на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/269589/). А вообще на эту тему есть уйма книг и статей.

В будущем, пожалуйста, указывайте источник (книгу и страницу). Я лично ее читал около двух лет назад и вспомнить какая именно это книга было непросто. Очень многое зависит от контекста.

P.p.s Лень сейчас искать оригинал книги, но почти уверен, что тут как представление перевели слово presentation, которое несет смысл совершенно несовпадающий с view.